# energy adjusted nutrient intake

Tags: epidemiology

I have a data on 7 nutrients (intake of 150 people - 75 men and 75 women). Can i do factor analysis to derive the nutrient intake pattern? If so shouldn't each nutrient be adjusted with the total energy intake?
I would like to do a nutrient intake pattern analysis with the data that I have. Intakes are available for protein, fat, carbohydrates, calcium, iron, vitamin A and vitamin C. Only protein and fat seems to be normally distributed. What should I do?

Comment: May explaining the context and data would help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should definitely adjusted the nutrient with total energy intake first (based on Willett's method). To choose which method to derive the nutrient intake pattern depends on what you want to accomplish, but principle component analysis and cluster analysis are frequently used.

Comment: Suppose if the data is secondary, how does one identify if the nutrient intakes have already been adjusted?